# Describe all bijective analytic maps from punctured unit disk to itself

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the unit disk and let $A=\mathbb{D}$-{$a,b,c$} where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{D}$. How can I describe all conformal automorphism or in other words bijective analytic functions $f:A\to A$? I feel like I should use the Riemann mapping theorem but I am not too sure how to. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Each such map extends to be holomorphic in $\mathbb D.$

Comment: @zhw. So re-define the function at $a,b,c$ by considering them as removable singularities and then use the Riemann mapping theorem?

Comment: I don't think the RMT comes into this. Rather it's knowledge of what holomorphic bijections of the disc look like.